# Issue with understanding RXJS Observable Output

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm fairly new to rxjs and trying to learn.

I was reading through [this medium article](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/reactive-programming-in-javascript-8373201a6618) and trying to understand this RXJS output:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs-es';
let output = Observable.interval(500)
             .map(i => [1,2,3,4,5,6][i]);

let result = output.map(num1 => num1)
    .filter(num1 => num1 > 4)
    .reduce((num1, num2) => num1 + num2);

result.subscribe(number => console.log(number));
```

> Output: 27

I don't understand how the output turned out to be 27 and how that reduce is working (and what are those two arguments for the reducer).

Can someone enlighten me what's happening? (I've tried to run it on codesandbox however it's throwing an error when I run this code)

Comment: This article has so many errors and weird stuff going for it, that I wouldn't even try to understand how he got 27. He's even using a really old version of rxjs, which is probably why you can't run it

Comment: Article is definitely wrong. Answer should be 11. I reconstructed it to work properly at https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ouwb5i?file=index.ts . reduce takes 2 arguments, first an accumulator to collect sum and second the current value on a stream 
 https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/reduce

Comment: rxjs-es is a library which was last updated 4 years ago and came never out of beta. Please don't even bother to use it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63605677/how-does-rxjs-reduce-in-case-there-is-no-matching-accumulator

Answer (score 1):

### Understanding `Filter` and `Reduce` Operators

As others have mentioned in the comments, the article you refer to is using an older version of rxjs that has a different syntax.  For this example I'll use the newer syntax that started in version 6.

In rxjs, there are various operators available to transform the values emitted through a stream. Typically these are imported like:

```
import { filter, reduce } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

There are also many generator functions available to create a stream of values.  `interval` is one of these functions that will create a stream that emits sequential integers every `n` milliseconds. Imported like:

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
```

Let's create a simple stream:

```
number$ = interval(1000); // emit number every 1 second
// output: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...
```

We can apply operators to this stream to transform the emissions:

The usage of `filter` is pretty simple.  It simply emits values that pass the given truth test (exactly like the `Array.filter()` method).

```
numbersLessThan4$ = numbers$.pipe(
    filter(number => number < 4)
);
// output: 0, 1, 2, 3
```

The `reduce` operator is a bit more complex and behaves just like the `Array.reduce()` method.  A function is applied to each emitted value and is able store a value that can be referenced when the next emission is evaluated.

`reduce` takes two parameters.  The first is a function that receives the current emission (`cur`) and the previous accumulated result (`acc`) and returns a new accumulated value.  The second is an initial value for `acc`.

example:

```
sumOfNumbers$ = numbers$.pipe(
    reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0)
);
```

So, let's look what `reduce` does when `numbers$` emits the first 3 numbers:

- 0

  - `cur` receives the current emission value `0`
  - `acc` starts with the provided default `0`
  - the expression `acc + cur` returns `0`
- 1

  - `cur` receives the current emission value `1`
  - `acc` receives the previously returned value `0`
  - the expression `acc + cur` returns `1`
- 2

  - `cur` receives the current emission value `2`
  - `acc` receives the previously returned value `1`
  - the expression `acc + cur` returns `3`

So this is cool.  We can get quite a lot of logic into a simple line of code.  One important thing about `reduce` is that it will not emit until the source observable completes.  Currently, `numbers$` never completes (`interval()` emits sequential integers indefinitely).

We can use the `take()` operator to complete the stream after a certain number of values are emitted.

Example:

```
numbers$ = interval(1000).pipe(take(5)); // completes after 5 emissions

sumOfNumbers$ = numbers$.pipe(
    // receives 5 values (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) and performs the logic described above.
    reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0) 
);
// output: 10
```

Multiple operators can be used to transform the emissions.  Simply provide multiple inside the `pipe()`:

```
sumOfNumbersLessThan4$ = numbers$.pipe(
    filter(number => number < 4),
    reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur, 0) 
);
// output: 6
```

Comment: I hope this helped.